# Laravel, get User id for BroadcastOn()

Tags: php, laravel

I'd need to get user's id for the channel name via BroadcastOn() function?

What I'm trying to do is:

New event:

```
event(new \App\Events\chat($message, $userid, $avatar, $username, $receiver, $msgid));
```

Event itself

```
public $message;
    public $user;
    public $avatar;
    public $username;
    public $receiver;
```

Construct:

```
public function __construct($message, $user, $avatar,$username,$receiver,$msgid) {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->avatar = $avatar;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->receiver = $receiver;
        $this->msgid = $msgid;

    }
```

Broadcast:

```
public function broadcastOn() {
        $user = \Auth::user()->id();
        return new Channel($user);
    }
```

And if I try to dd \Auth::user(); it gives me null, which I suppose is that user is not recognized in the events via auth. Is there a way to pass user to broadcastOn() somehow so I could define it as a channel name?

Comment: are you running it from command line>

Comment: No, running it from controller.

Comment: I mean to say , do the controller run from command line?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It gets fired up by user after sending message and who's logged in online. Naturally couldn't get the user if I'd fire it up via command line :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can do like below as you have `$user` already in constructor

```
public function broadcastOn() {
{
 return ['channel_'.$this->user->id];
}
```

Or pass user id

```
public function __construct($message, $user, $avatar,$username,$receiver,$msgid,$userid) {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->avatar = $avatar;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->receiver = $receiver;
        $this->msgid = $msgid;
       $this->userid= $userid;

    }
```

and then

```
public function broadcastOn() {
    {
     return ['channel_'.$this->userid];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly :). So I don't actually need to use "new Channel" when I do the return? It was pretty much not documented at all and I've been stuck with the past 6 hours with this, you made my day :)